# .HTACCESS REWRITE

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I need to rewrite this :

```
http://www.xxx.co.uk/holidays/resort/courchevel/chalet/chalet-xx/pricing.html
```

to this:

```
http://www.xxx.co.uk/holidays/courchevel/chalet-xx/pricing.html
```

though the chalet name and resort changes so i would need the $1 and $2 in there i think

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Sorry just read my question and i need it the other way round sorry i want the lower one to rewrite to the one above. Sorry had my sons first birthday on the weekend and still shattered form it

Comment: you did not use resort in second URL. where I should put it?

Comment: I made the mistake of highlighting the URL to paste it in a comment, but instead clicking on 'Open link in new tab'...

Comment: -1: same old question which has been answered many times... shows no research effort at all.

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood your question correctly, something along these lines should do it (based on your edit)...

```
^holidays/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/pricing.html /holidays/resort/$1/chalet/$2/pricing.html
```